# Run Inline ASP code on a Published Master Page

Tags: master-page, publishing-site, asp.net, cache, sputility

I'd like to use the SPUtility.MakeBrowserCacheSafeLayoutsUrl method in my published master page (used in a publishing site) in order to [force SharePoint to stop caching](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/57874/how-to-avoid-caching-issue-when-using-custom-javascript-and-css-deployed-under#answer-74300) my JavaScript and CSS files.

If I was working with a traditional .aspx page, this would suffice:

```
 <script type="text/jscript" src="<%=Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.MakeBrowserCacheSafeLayoutsUrl("projectName/scripts/plugins/tapes_report_definition.js", false)%>" ></script>
```

But being a published Master Page, the tagging concept is a bit different. For example, this is what a JavaScript reference looks like:

```
<!--MS:<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sharing.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false">-->
<!--ME:</SharePoint:ScriptLink>-->
```

So I've been trying various ways to include that inline call to the cache method; here's what I've tried:

**Simple script tag with inline code**

```
<script src="<%=Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.MakeBrowserCacheSafeLayoutsUrl("IntrinsiQ.UserPortal.SharePoint/scripts/portal-main.js", false)%>"></script>
```

*Result: '<', hexadecimal value 0x3C, is an invalid attribute character*

**Script tag surrounded in SharePoint MS/ME tags**

```
<!--MS:<script src="<%= Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.MakeBrowserCacheSafeLayoutsUrl("IntrinsiQ.UserPortal.SharePoint/scripts/portal-mainx.js", false) %>">-->
<!--ME:</script>-->
```

*Result: Invalid SharePoint markup*

**Script tag surrounded in SharePoint MS/ME tags with Encoding**

```
    <!--MS:<script src="&#60;%= Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.MakeBrowserCacheSafeLayoutsUrl("IntrinsiQ.UserPortal.SharePoint/scripts/portal-mainx.js", false) %&#62;">-->
    <!--ME:</script>-->
```

*Result: Invalid SharePoint markup*

**ScriptLink tag**

```
<!--MS:<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="<%=Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.MakeBrowserCacheSafeLayoutsUrl("IntrinsiQ.UserPortal.SharePoint/scripts/portal-main.js", false)%>" runat="server">-->
<!--ME:</SharePoint:ScriptLink>-->
```

*Result: Invalid SharePoint markup*

**ScriptLink tag with encoding**

```
<!--MS:<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="&#60;%=Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.MakeBrowserCacheSafeLayoutsUrl("IntrinsiQ.UserPortal.SharePoint/scripts/portal-main.js", false)%&#62;" runat="server">-->
<!--ME:</SharePoint:ScriptLink>-->
```

*Result: Invalid SharePoint markup*

***Note:***
I tested the encodings with "<" = `&#60;` or `&lt;` and ">", and `&#62;` or `&gt;` for good measeure.

Answer (score 2):

Matt,

You can create an user control to handle this in code. You can then add the control to the master page.

Take a look at these two examples and let me know if I can assist.

[Inject dynamic javascript using MasterPage](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10861/inject-dynamic-javascript-using-masterpage)

[Programmatically add JS/CSS to pages](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18652/programmatically-add-js-css-to-pages)

Comment: That makes sense; I'll take a look into this.